# rails 4 pass object between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Queries Controller` which handles the results of an API request and I'm trying to pass that api object to another controller without having to persist the information to the database (the point of the app is returning a list of movies available in a certain zipcode and then allowing a user to view those results and create an event with friends around that movie, so there's no need to save the movie information in my database when the api call is made since it returns a lot of movies)

Here is my `create` method in the `Queries Controller`:

```
def create
    @query = Query.new
    @query.zip = query_params['zip']
    @query.date = query_params['date']
    @results = data(@query.zip, @query.date)
    redirect_to results_path, :results => @results
  end
```

and the `results` method which it gets passed to

```
def results
end
```

and then the corresponding `Results view` where I am just trying to display the results object:

```
<h3>Index</h3>

<%= results %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**MVC**

My immediate thought is your thoughts are against the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (on which Rails is based):

[image]

Controllers are meant to take a `request` from HTTP, and use it to manipulate the data on your screen *through* a model. The model is then able to provide the `data` you require, which can be passed to the view.

Sending requests inter-controller is against this pattern IMO - you'll be much better manipulating the data in a single `controller` `action`, and then pulling that data from the model.

Having said that, I think you are doing things relatively well, although you may wish to consider refactoring at system-level.

--

**Fix**

You *should* be able to pass your `instance variable` to your `results` action through the [`params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) object, as described by `mjhlobdell`:

```
#app/controllers/queries_controller.rb
Class QueriesController < ApplicationController
   def query
       ...
       redirect_to results_path(results: @results)
   end
end

#app/controllers/results_controller.rb
Class ResultsController < ApplicationController
    def results
       @results = params[:results]
    end 
end
```

You should be able to use this to pass the data you need.

An alternative way would be to manipulate / render the response directly in the `Queries` `create` method, as here:

```
#app/controllers/queries_controller.rb
Class QueriesController < ApplicationController
   def create
       ...
       render :results
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the results in the params hash to the `results` method

```
def create
  @query = Query.new
  @query.zip = query_params['zip']
  @query.date = query_params['date']
  @results = data(@query.zip, @query.date)
  redirect_to results_path(:results => @results)
end
```

Then:

```
def results
  @results = params[:results]
end
```

In the view:

```
<h3>Index</h3>

<%= @results %>
```